# Add image source link on the Image

Tags: image

I want to add an hyperlink on the image :

here is the example : http://aff248.teensdigest.com/articles/766?page=1

I want to use few images on my website with that i want to show the image source.

So how can we add a link of image source on the image itself. I tried with the css but i don't know how to put the link exactly on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample web site is using CSS to overlay the image with an href for "Source" like this:

[Source](http://img.wallpapergang.com/282processed/Chloe%20Grace%20Moretz%20Cute%20Wallpapers.jpg)

And in one of the CSS stylesheets, they define the class citation. Check out the second stylesheet in your sample.